# Adding numbers formatted as currency in animated numbers (10,000)

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to create a loading animation for my activity.so I used the below code :

```
private void startCountAnimation() {
        animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(1000, 9000);
        animator.setDuration(500);
        animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        animator.addUpdateListener((animation) -> {
            tvCost.setText(animation.getAnimatedValue().toString());
        });
        animator.start();
    }
```

this will count 1000 to 9000. but I want to have the currency format while it is counting. so I want the result shown like 1,000 to 9,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the number like this:

```
tvCost.setText(String.format("%10.0f", animation.getAnimatedValue()));
```

or for local currency:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String currency = formatter.format(animation.getAnimatedValue());
tvCost.setText(currency);
```